# Query duplicates after each onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, datatables

I have an add feature that runs an insert query (using PDO).

The first insert works accordingly.  It's the second run, and every run after that causes the query to duplicate times 2.

I have no idea why this is happening.

The user makes a selection, which populates a datatable (example1).  They can then select one of the records (or lanes) which populates another datatable (example2).

Here is the initial onClick event:

```
$('#example1').on('click', 'tr > .laneClick', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable();
  const rowData = dataTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

  let partnerCode = rowData['partner_code'];
  let partnerName = rowData['partner_name'];
  let groupName = rowData['groupname'];

  let lanecriteria = {
    partnerCode: partnerCode,
    partnerName: partnerName,
    groupName: groupName
  }

  displayLaneRecords(lanecriteria); 
});
```

Here is the function displayLaneRecords, which displays the second datatable called "example2" after the .laneClick onClick event:

```
function displayLaneRecords(lanecriteria){
  
  if(lanecriteria == ""){
    let data = '';
  }
  else{ 
    let data = {
        lanecriteria: {
            partnerCode: lanecriteria.partnerCode,
            vesselProfile: lanecriteria.vesselProfile,
            salesRep: lanecriteria.salesRep
        }
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/getLaneData.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);    
      var table = $('#example2').DataTable({    
        "data": jsonObject,
        "columns": [  
          // data columns
        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
          {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Lane',
            className: 'addLane btn btn-primary btn-sm',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config){
              // opens the form for processing
              $('#addLaneModal').modal('show'); 
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     console.log('fail: '+ errorThrown);
     return false;
    }
  }); // end ajaxcall
  
  // here is where the form process will occur      

} // end displayLaneRecords();
```

As you will see, the form process will occur within the displayLaneRecords() function. I had to do this so when the process is complete, I can repopulate the datatable without refreshing.

Here is the form process:

```
$('#addLaneSubmit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  let partnerCode = $('#addlanepartnercode').val();
  let partnerName = $('#addlanepartnername').val();
  let groupName = $('#addlanegroupname').val();

  let addlanecriteria = {
    partnerCode: partnerCode,
    partnerName: partnerName,
    groupName: groupName
  }

  $.post('api/editLane.php', {addlanecriteria:addlanecriteria}, function(data){
    if(data.indexOf('Error') > 1){
        $('.message').text(data);
        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
        return false();
    }
    else{
        $('.message').text(data);
        $('#messageModal').modal('show');
        $('#messageModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
            $("#addLaneModal").modal('hide');                   
            displayLaneRecords(lanecriteria); // call displayLaneRecords to refresh the table
        });
    } 
  });
});
```

The actual PHP process called editLane.php looks like this:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['addlanecriteria'])){
    $value = $_POST['addlanecriteria'];

    $partnerCode = isset($value['partnerCode']) ? $value['partnerCode'] : '';
    $partnerName = isset($value['partnerName']) ? $value['partnerName'] : '';
    $groupName = isset($value['groupName']) ? $value['groupName'] : '';

    try{
      $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $insert = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`partner_code`, `partner_name`, `group_name`) VALUES (:newpartnercode, :newpartnername, :newgroupname)");

      $insert->execute([
        'newpartnercode' => $partnerCode ,
        'newpartnername' => $partnerName ,
        'newgroupname' => $groupName
      ]);

      if($insert){
        echo "Success: New Lane has been added.";
      }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
?>
```

I tried to minimize as much code as I could.

All of the above works without any visible errors.  When the form is submitted, a new record is inserted into the table, and the datatable refreshes without the page refreshing.

The problem occurs when the user adds another record - the query duplicates, and instead of inserting 1 record, 2 are inserted.  If they add another record, the query will insert 4 records.

What can I try next?

Comment: Are you sure `$('#addLaneSubmit').on('click'...` is only called once ? Try to put an alert(1) on first line of the function. If you're getting more than one alert than you're click event is being executed multiple times

Comment: @SelimAchour - The alert initially fires once.  But every time I add a new record, the alert starts to fire multiple times.  I don't get it.

Comment: That means this line `$('#addLaneSubmit').on('click'` is called multiple times and every time it's executed it adds another click handler on the same element. So now every time you click it fires the event for every click handler. You need to make it so this line is only executed once. Or use `$(...)[0].onclick = function() { .......... }` as this method overdires the handler every time